# Plot doesn't work in Visual studio code but work in REPL

Tags: plot, julia

I have the following code

```
using Plots

V = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9]
plot(V[:,1,1])
```

When I run this with REPL, I could see the graph with GKS QtTerm program.

However, if I run this with Visual studio code, nothing happens.

Is there anything else I should do in order to plot in Visual studio code?

Comment: Did you install the Julia extension in VS Code? Also, do you use WSL in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Using Julia 1.6 and the Julia VS Code Extension version 1.4.3 I can verify that this works locally.

[image: VS Code in Julia]

If you have not already, please make sure to follow the setup steps mentioned here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/julia

In the settings for the Julia extension, make sure you have "Use Plot Pane" enabled:

[image: Plot Pane in VS Code]

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the Visual Studio Code extension. Most of the time, when I "execute active file in REPL", the plots won't be rendered. But if I afterwards select the `plot()` line and then "execute code in REPL", the plot is displayed.

Comment: I would open an issue an try to see if you can give steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Plots would simply not show up when Running without Debugging (ctrl-F5). However, the plots would show as normal when pressing the play button in the top-right corner,i.e. running "Julia: Execute Active File in REPL".

(from your question I am not sure whether this is precisely the issue you are raising, or that this would suffice as a solution)